# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+{1}/{5x})^{2x+6}=e^{{2}/{5}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}  \left(1+\dfrac{1}{5x}\right)^{2x+6}=e^{\frac{2}{5}}$

I believe I can rewrite this as $\lim_{x\to\infty}  \left(1+\dfrac{1}{5x}\right)^{2x+6}$ as $\dfrac{(1+\frac{1}{5x})^{2x}}{(1+\frac{1}{5x})^{6}}$. The deominator will get to 1 as x approaches infinity, but what about the numerator? How do you solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{5x}\right)^{2x+6} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{5x}\right)^{5x}\right]^{2/5}\times\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{5x}\right)^{6}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=5x$ then $$2x+6 = (2/5)y +6$$

$$  \lim_{x\to\infty}  \left(1+\dfrac{1}{5x}\right)^{2x+6}=$$

$$ \lim_{y\to\infty}  \left(1+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{y(2/5)} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{5x}\right)^{6}=$$

$$ e^{\frac{2}{5}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is just as good. Note that:

$$\big(1+\frac{1}{5x}\big)^{2x}=\bigg(\big(1+\frac{1/5}{x}\big)^{x}\bigg)^{2}$$

Now the expressions in the parentheses on the inside is the classic limit definition of $e^x$ for $x=\frac{1}{5}$ and so taking the limit gives the desired result.